# Document management system for asp.net application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a requirement. One application is developed in asp.net. In that application we have a file upload control is there. As of now if you upload any file by using file upload control that files will be saved into the file system.
Now the client wants document management system in share point instead of file system. But UI is not changed(UI designed in ASP.Net).
How we can achive this without change the UI in asp.net and how the files will be saved into the document management system instead of file system.
Pl z help me on this issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily setup a SharePoint farm (probably a simple and free SharePoint Foundation would be enough) and use it only as a back-end system to store your files.

SharePoint stores files in document libraries (and technically, they all end up in the SQL DB).

You can use your SP programmatically from your ASP.NET application: by using OOTB REST end-points or client C# Object Model, you can easily remote control your SP installation to create new document libraries on the fly, parameter them (versioning settings, security settings, metadata, etc.) and upload documents in it.

For your users to read the documents, two options: either a direct link to the SharePoint document, or a page of your ASP.NET application that would act as a "proxy".

[Edit]
Here are some links:

- Uploading files from C# code to a remote SharePoint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849835/3439544
- Look at the second screenshot of that question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6244029/3439544. Your own application is more or less equivalent the 3 vertical blocks in the middle of that schema. The SharePoint C# client code would run on "custom ASP.NET app".
- All other basic operations from SP client API (C#): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/FP179912.aspx (including creation of a new list)

Comment: Can you share any links like this kind of scenarios. Actually i don't know much about the CSOM and REST api's. Mostly i worked only SOM.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SharePoint Farm** (Free version of SharePoint (**SharePoint Foundation**)) and use it for back-end system to store your files in different Libraries and Lists.

Here, you can manage your documents' versions and metadata. You can upload and download documents from your website by either providing them direct url from SharePoint or create facility on your website for that.

You can connect your existing Asp.Net website to your SharePoint Farm using:

- SharePoint Client Object Model (C#) [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)
- SharePoint Client Object Model (JavaScript) [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)
- Rest API [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

You can get more information about SharePoint CSOM development from below links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138322/Exploring-SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Capa
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/create-update-delete-a-list-using-client-object-model-cso/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript